# The server returns Compilation Error

Tags: asp.net

I'm using the freebie plan on somee.com. About one month ago i first upload my asp.net website and it ran without any errors. Now i've made many change to the website with VS2010 and decide to upload a new version. But the server keep showing "Compilation Error" with message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'pwblog.BusinessObject.ArticleBo' does not contain a definition for 'FormatDate' and no extension method 'FormatDate' accepting a first argument of type 'pwblog.BusinessObject.ArticleBo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
> Line 61:             pagedDataSource.DataSource = articleBo.FormatDate(Articles);

Here is my FormatDate function:

```
internal Article[] FormatDate(Article[] source)
{
    if (source != null && source.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Article art in source)
        {
            art.DatePost = DateTime.Parse(art.DatePost).ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

Actually there's no problem with the function. When I debug with VS2010 it runs well. The only difference I realize between the old one and this newly uploaded one is that I changed my MSSQL from 2008 SP2 to 2008 R2 SP2, due to the fact that I've changed my OS from windows 7 to windows 8.

Also, here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="AssignmentsFinalConnectionString" connectionString="workstation id=pwblog01.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=pwblog;pwd=Duc123456;data source=pwblog01.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=pwblog01"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="AssignmentsFinalConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AssignmentsFinal.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
  
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Web\Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" defaultUrl="Web\"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    <globalization uiCulture="vi" culture="vi-VN"/>

<customErrors mode="Off" >
</customErrors>
  </system.web>

        <system.webServer>
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <add value="index.aspx" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
        </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/S8sY9zMJ))

Well, I don't believe that the MSSQL cause the problem, but I don't have any other clue. About the error, there's a very long detail messasge attached, so I don't put it here. So, any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: What is the actual line giving the error message? You're showing the definition but not the actual call.

Comment: I post the source error. As i said it runs in local correctly, just throws error after uploaded to online host. Please take a closer look at this link (my error site): http://pwblog.somee.com/Web/default.aspx

Comment: A method declared `internal` could be accessed only within files from the same assembly. Is it your `pagedDataSource` in the same assembly? Could you try to change your access modifier to `public` and check if it works then?

Comment: If you change `internal` to `public` does it solve your error?

Comment: You can post XML just fine, just post is as code block.

Comment: Sorry sir, i've just checked all my question and accepted the answers. Thanks for reminding me :) @steve i changed it and problem's not solved

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using the function in a wrong way.

you're invoking it as if it was an Articlebo class method; or with an Articlebo instance argument instead of an Article array (I guess Articlebo inherits from Article)

you should post the wrong line anyway

Comment: tks i posted it. Yes FormatDate is a public (internal) method of class ArticleBo, and articleBo is an instance of that class. The parameter i gave it is an array of Article (Article[])

Comment: Change internal modifier to public if you're using it from page code (instead of code behind)

Comment: Change it to public if class Articlebo is in other assembly than using assembly and make sure the assemblies are updated in the server bin folder